# Carriage Return in VBscript?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a script in VBscript and I need to include line breaks or carriage returns. I was  using the following code:

```
objSelection.TypeParagraph()
```

But this creates to big of a space between lines. The best way I can think to explain it is, when you are in Microsoft word, and you type a line, if you were to press Shift + Enter, you would get two separate lines close together, whereas pressing just Enter will do a full Carriage return (which I don't want). I will demonstrate here.

How can I achieve the same result as 'Shift + Enter' but through VBscript?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're asking about Word VBA, you can do it like this:

```
objSelection.TypeText(Chr(11))
```

Generally, if you can't find out how to do something in VBA that you can do in the application, just record a macro while you perform the required steps and then look and see what VBA has been generated.

Comment: Note that there are built-in string constants for many characters. `Chr(11)` is `vbVerticalTab`. I find those easier to read and remember than the ASCII codes. ([VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh277t8e%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [VB6/VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199336.aspx) work the same here.)